# way to automate git repositories cloning

Tags: bash, ssh, git, clone

I have to clone several repositories on the VM-s and then building software on them.
I have pretty nice build script but there is one issue. Before build, several repos should be cloned, and after some security updates, I am not allowed to add my public key to git server and also only supported protocol is ssh.

The cloning command looks like follow:

```
git clone ssh://userA@git-ger-XXX.com:YYYY/repoB
```

but there are plenty of them and passing password after each of them is really annoying and time-consuming.

What I am trying to do is to pass automatically password to clone command.
I was trying add userA:passwordA@git-ger.... but it works only for HTTPS, not ssh. I know that I have to switch to some automatic tools like ansible to make automatic deployment but it took me a lot of time to rewrite whole building process.

My question is how I can automatically pass a password to clone repo, without changing anything on the server. Ideally, would be to do this from bash level.
I was trying reading lines after typing git clone but it also didn't work for me.
Any help will be appreciated

Comment: you can try `sshpass`. It should work also for your use case.

Answer (score 2):

IMO the best solution is using a custom `GIT_ASKPASS` helper and deliver the password as another environment variable. So for example, create a file `git-askpass-helper.sh` as:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec echo "$GIT_PASSWORD"
```

and then run `git clone https://username@hostname/repo` with environment variables `GIT_ASKPASS=/path/to/git-askpass-helper.sh` and `GIT_PASSWORD=nuclearlaunchcodes`.